# why does it say .setDescription is not a function? (RichEmbed in JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm creating an embed for my command `/quotes` which is to be used for my discord bot.

Here's the code:

```
if(cmd === `${prefix}quotes`){

  quotes = new Discord.RichEmbed();
  q1 = "  -- Andres Iniesta";
  q2 = "  -- French Poverb";
  q3 = "  -- www.quotesgate.com"

  .setDescription("**__Here are some inspirational quotes!__**")
  .setColor("#319786")
  .addField("**Some people like you, some people don't. In the end, you just have to be yourself.**". q1)
  .addField("**Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace**", q2)
  .addField("Don’t forget you’re human. It’s okay to have a meltdown. Just don’t unpack and live there. Cry it out. Then refocus on where you’re headed", q3)

  return message.channel.send(quotes);
}
```

I keep receiving an error on my console that .setDescription is not a function

```
/ | TomatoHeadIdiot is now active in 4 servers!
(node:7448) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: "  -- www.quotesgate.com".setDescription is not a function
```

Comment: please clarify: there should be an object before `.setDescription`, shouldn't it? Or those are some methods added to `String.prototype`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have a semicolon after the line `q3 = "  -- www.quotesgate.com"` so it pastes the next line right after it. So it basically becomes

```js
q3 = "  -- www.quotesgate.com".setDescription("**__Here are some inspirational quotes!__**")
```

which won't work ofcourse. I'm assuming you want to call the `setDescription` and `addField` on the embed so you need to change your code to the following:

```js
if(cmd === `${prefix}quotes`){

  q1 = "  -- Andres Iniesta";
  q2 = "  -- French Poverb";
  q3 = "  -- www.quotesgate.com";

  quotes = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setDescription("**__Here are some inspirational quotes!__**")
    .setColor("#319786")
    .addField("**Some people like you, some people don't. In the end, you just have to be yourself.**", q1)
    .addField("**Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace**", q2)
    .addField("Don’t forget you’re human. It’s okay to have a meltdown. Just don’t unpack and live there. Cry it out. Then refocus on where you’re headed", q3);
  
  return message.channel.send(quotes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(cmd === `${prefix}quotes`){

  quotes = new Discord.RichEmbed();
  q1 = "  -- Andres Iniesta";
  q2 = "  -- French Poverb";
  q3 = "  -- www.quotesgate.com";

  quotes.setDescription("**__Here are some inspirational quotes!__**");
  quotes.setColor("#319786");
  quotes.addField("**Some people like you, some people don't. In the end, you just have to be yourself.**". q1);
  quotes.addField("**Wherever life plants you, bloom with grace**", q2);
  quotes.addField("Don’t forget you’re human. It’s okay to have a meltdown. Just don’t unpack and live there. Cry it out. Then refocus on where you’re headed", q3);

  return message.channel.send(quotes);

}
```

Done! :-)